C++ Program Not Outputting Text in Windows Terminal Even After Successful Compilation With g++
So recently I've downloaded MinGW for my Windows laptop so I can use g++ to compile my personal C++ code, as I'm a CS student learning GNU utilities because long story short, it's what the curriculum wants me to do.
This is the code I'm having a bit of a tussle with (I know it's a basic hello world program, I made it for testing):
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
cout<<"hello world!" <<endl;
return 0;
}

When I use this command: g++ -Wall helloworld.cpp -o helloworld, the code is compiled without a single error, and an application called helloworld is created in the current directory. However, when I run the application using ./helloworld in Terminal, it doesn't output any text.
I've compiled programs with Visual Studio before and they have outputted text fine.
Also worth noting is that when I used the command gcc -Wall helloagain.c -o helloagain on this C program I made below, the program actually outputs text when I run it.
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("Hello Again.");
  return 0;
}

Can anyone tell me why this is? Did I install MinGW wrong? Did I forget to do something for g++? Did I screw up one minor thing on my computer that caused this whole mess? Maybe re-installing MinGW might work, but I'm not sure.

The likeliest explanation is that your program is silently crashing. And the likeliest explanation for that is that at run time your program is loading a version of the standard C++ library that is incompatible with the version that you compiled with. So yes this is an installation problem. Did you use MSYS2 to install g++? If not then wipe out everything g++ or mingw related and start again.

If you have already installed some GNU utilities I would guess that the conflict is there. So wipe those out too. You'll find that many GNU utilities are available from MSYS2 as well.

You should try running the code in a debugger or at least check what the exit code is, that'll give you more information. Most likely is that the standard library dll is either not on your path or an incompatible version is

try system("pause") at the end

@john I've currently deleted all the mingw files and installed msys2. I'm currently navigating my way around it. Thanks for the header.
